Only PHP code displayed instead of the results in "http://localhost/info.php"
When I try to access phpinfo.php from my browser in Windows 10, I see only the code displayed without execution.
This is how it looks
I believe I have set up everything correctly.
My Apache httpd.config includes the following:
LoadModule php_module "C:\php-8.3.8\php8apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:\php-8.3.8"
ServerName localhost:80

My phpinfo.php file is present in C:\Apache24\htdocs and has the following code:
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
After all of this, when I try to run httpd -t in my cmd as admin, I get the following:
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::2e86:1b99:e3c4:74c8. 
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK

There is no error in error log.
The access log says the following:
::1 - - [19/Jun/2024:14:51:52 +0530] "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 200 19

How do I make it work?
